# Periodic graphics issues after rebooting

Tags: boot, graphics

Whenever I reboot my computer, I take on a ~50/50 gamble that I will have display issues. These manifest in several ways, but the most salient is the launcher graphics. Compare the following two screenshots, taken 10 minutes apart after fresh boots:

[image: Bad graphics]
[image: Good graphics]

Whenever I get a launcher looking like the first one with the boxes around the icons, I know I have to reboot (sometimes twice) or other bad things await. E.g., Emacs' font scaling won't work on my external monitor.

I'm on 16.04, and I've captured syslog for both "good boots" and "bad boots", but I'm not sure what to be looking for. I'll update this question with relevant info to help identify and solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Go to Unity Tweak Tool >> Launcher >> Icon Background and select "Colored Edge".

There's maybe an issue with Icon background sets to "Alternated for each workspace"

Comment: Toggling that setting doesn't do anything for me. I had it set to "Open applications only". I think that it's only a symptom though of a deeper issue